# Combined flair score lower than SO-only score

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, flair, combined-flair

How is this possible? My combined Stack Exchange rep score is lower than my Stack Overflow score. As far as I know, I only have a Stack Overflow account and a Meta account (which is below 200, so it shouldn't count at all). Maybe the combined score is cached and updated only periodically?

[image: Combined Score screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the other numbers aren't updated either now my reputation is increased. I seems that the image is cached for hours (24 hours, I read in another answer).

I could understand why, but it is a pity because it would have more *flair* if the image contains a more up-to-date reputation.

Maybe the image could be updated more often, or may it could be updated earlier if a reputation changes more than a certain minimum or more than a certain percentage in respect of the reputation shown in the flair.

-update-

Apparently the page is updates between then and now. It still takes a while for the flair to be updated, but at least the explanation near the combined flair now clearly states that it can take up to 36 hours.

[image]

Comment: We have to cache the image for a while to maintain reasonable performance...this may change in the future but it's by-design for now.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen to me on SU and I emailed the wonderful guys at `team@stackexchange.com` and and they said it is cached between 24-48 hours and in 10 hours time it was fixed.